# Analytic bounded in the half right plane is identically zero provided that $\limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ $\frac{\log|f(xe^{ni})|}{x}\leq-n$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove that an analytic bounded function in the right half complex plane $\mathbb C_{+}$ is the null function, that is $f=0$ if we suppose that f verifies : $\limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ $\frac{\log|f(xe^{ni})|}{x}\leq-n$; $n\geq1$ and $e^{ni}\in \mathbb C_{+}$. I tried Phragmen-lindelof theorem but i did not manage to solve the problem. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Your title and the first sentence contradict the rest of your question. ($e^{-z}$ is bounded on the right half plane.) Please clarify the question a little.

Comment: Sorry. The title is incomplete. It is identically zero provided that we have the condition with the limsup cited before. So f verifies this condition :  limsupx→∞ log|f(xeni)|x≤−n. Thank you mrf.

Comment: I am still working on it but i am stuck. Any idea?